# Is `@=n` revision specifier the same as `@n,n` in Perforce file specifications?

Tags: perforce

Is the `@=n` syntax identical to the `@n,n` syntax?

For example, is

```
p4 integ //someotherbranch/...@12345,12345 ...
```

identical to

```
p4 integ //someotherbranch/...@=12345 ...
```

?

Comment: Language specific / implementation type questions like this are better asked on StackOverflow.  Currently, there are 2 votes to migrate there with 3 more needed to complete the migration.  You may also flag your question and request a moderator to migrate more quickly.  It may take a few hours for the reviews to complete or for the mods to handle your flag.  Thanks for being patient.

Comment: If you type, in the command line, `p4 help undoc` and look for "Relative Revisions", you'll find info on `@=n` and some other less common revision specifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access shelved revisions you do need to use the "@=n" syntax specifically, which is handled as a special case for changelists with shelved files.  Otherwise they end up being the same.

If you want to get really technical "@n,n" is syntactic sugar for "@>=n,@<=n", which is logically going to match the same set of depot revisions as "@=n" (except for the shelve special case, which involves revisions that aren't actually committed to the depot yet).